# Proving properties of sets in Inox/Welder

Tags: scala, formal-verification, leon

I would like to proof some properties of sets on [Inox](https://github.com/epfl-lara/inox)/[Welder](https://github.com/epfl-lara/welder) but I'm lacking examples that help me to figure out how to do so. Say I want to proof:

> content(y::xs).contains(x) && x != y ==> content(xs).contains(x)

I define the property:

```
def property(xs: Expr) =
  forall("x"::A,"y"::A){case (x,y) 
    content(ConsA(y,xs)).contains(x) && x !== y ==> content(xs).contains(x)
  }
```

But it turns out that this property will not compile because it is not well formulated (apparently the wrong parts are .contains, &&, !==...)

So, what is the right way to formulate the property?. Here I'm assuming I have a content function defined as:

```
val contentFunction = mkFunDef(contentID)("A") { case Seq(aT) => (
    Seq("l" :: T(list)(aT)), SetType(aT), { case Seq(l) =>
      if_ (l.isInstOf(T(cons)(aT))) {
        SetAdd(E(contentID)(aT)(l.asInstOf(T(cons)(aT)).getField(tail)), l.asInstOf(T(cons)(aT)).getField(head))
        } else_ {
          FiniteSet(Seq.empty, aT)
        }
    })
  }
```

Regarding the proof part imagine I'm given the function:

```
def without(x: A, xs: List[A]) = xs match{
   case Nil() => Nil()
   case y :: ys if(x == y) => without(x,ys)
   case y :: ys if(x != y) => y :: without(x,ys)  
}
```

that should remove x from list xs and say I want to proof that

> content(without(x,l)) == content(l) -- Set(x)

Can you give a sketch of how to do it? Should I be using the [BuiltInNames](https://github.com/epfl-lara/welder/blob/456ed7f7335fb77a1cd16b1859cf33c29bff1429/src/main/scala/welder/parsing/BuiltInNames.scala) such as SetDifference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Compilation Error

The compilation error you are seeing might come from the missing arrow after the `case` in your formulation of the property. Also, be sure to use the right identifier for `content`.

```
def property(xs: Expr) =
  forall("x"::A,"y"::A) { case (x,y) =>
    contentID(ConsA(y,xs)).contains(x) && x !== y ==> contentID(xs).contains(x)
  }
```

Otherwise, the property looks correctly encoded using the Inox DSL.

#### Proof of Property

Regarding the proof itself, it don't think the `without` function is entirely necessary. The proof should go smoothly by structural induction on the list `xs`.

```
structuralInduction(property(_), "xs" :: T(List)(A)) { case (ihs, goal) =>
  ihs.expression match {
    case C(`Cons`, head, tail) => // Your case for Cons here.
    case C(`Nil`)              => // Your case for Nil here.
  }
}
```

The [ListAndTrees](https://github.com/epfl-lara/welder/blob/master/src/example/scala/ListsAndTrees.scala) showcases many such proofs.

#### `BuiltInName`

Regarding the `BuiltInNames` class, it is used in the parser of Inox expressions that is currently being developed within Welder. This very likely will be put in a separate project very soon.

This parser is used within Welder so that you can write Inox expressions using a somewhat friendlier syntax. For instance, your property could be stated as:

```
def property(xs: Expr) =
  e"forall x, y. contains(content(Cons(y, $xs)), x) && x != y ==> contains(content($xs), x)"
```

#### Inox Expressions

One last point. If you are looking for an exhaustive list of the different constructs available in Inox, have a look at the [Expressions](https://github.com/epfl-lara/inox/blob/master/src/main/scala/inox/ast/Expressions.scala) file in Inox.